# canvas ctx.stroke() no working/displaying properly (Javascript, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, canvas, webcam

I have the webcam stream on a canvas and am having trouble displaying a rectangle on top. The webcam stream works.
The issue is that the rectangle does not appear, and sometimes, there is a quick flash of the rectangle (and pretty blurry too...)

webcam to canvas setup:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('.photo');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// gets the video stream from the user's webcam
function getVideo() {
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: false
}).then(localMediaStream => {
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
  video.play();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('oh no', err);
});
}

// Applies the webcam stream to a canvas
function paintToCanvas() {
 const width = video.videoWidth;
 const height = video.videoHeight;
 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;

 return setInterval(() => {
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
 }, 16);
}
```

draw rectangle on top:

```
 function drawRectangle() {
  ctx.rect(150, 150, 50, 30);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.stroke();
 }
 drawRectangle();
```

I have tried different strokes, linewidths, and areas but same results.
What am I doing wrong? why it sometimes flashing in and out (upon page load) and not staying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval

That way your drawing will happen when the browser updates it's viewport.

[Drawing a shape in Canvas on repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222729/drawing-a-shape-in-canvas-on-repeat)

```
 function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
 }

function paintToCanvas() {
 const width = video.videoWidth;
 const height = video.videoHeight;
 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;
 requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tschallacka, the link help me find a fix.

Comment: When an answer works for you you can click the checkmark to indicate to future visitors that this was the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I added to fix it:

```
  let startTime;
  const interval=1;

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  function animate(t){
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   if(!startTime){startTime=t;}
   if(t-startTime<interval){return;}
   startTime=t;
   drawRectangle();
  }
```

every milli seconds (my choice) the shape is drawn. tested and works.
I stopped calling drawRectangle outside of a function and there is no more flash upon page load either.